# ITEM_COUNT column is missing from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION in Spring Batch 2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am migrating my application from Spring Batch 1.1.4 to Spring Batch 2.2.7 and I am facing issues mapping the columns from 1.x schema to 2.x schema for table - `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION`.

Earlier, `ITEM_COUNT` was part of this table, but it no longer exists now? Where should I get the `ITEM_COUNT` now? I don't see any other table as well which holds this value.

Here are the links for the metadata schemas for both the versions.

1.x - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-old/1.1.x/spring-batch-docs/reference/html-single/index.html
2.2.x - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've added a lot more granularity by replacing the single `ITEM_COUNT` with the following columns:

```
READ_COUNT
FILTER_COUNT
WRITE_COUNT
READ_SKIP_COUNT
WRITE_SKIP_COUNT
PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT
ROLLBACK_COUNT
```

The former `ITEM_COUNT` from 1.x aligns with `WRITE_COUNT` now.

Comment: I was going through their JIRAs and got this. [BATCH-774](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-774). This says ````ITEM_COUNT```` gets splitted into read/filter/write counts. Does that mean ````ITEM_COUNT```` is the summation of all these?

Comment: @divinedragon I'd say no : if you work on 10 items and everything goes well, you'll have `READ_COUNT = 10 + PROCESS_COUNT = 10 + WRITE_COUNT = 10` so the sum would be `30`

Comment: Thrax is right. `ITEM_COUNT` maps only to `WRITE_COUNT`. The other new columns provide additional detail which I, for one, find very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation from the links you provided, here's what's written for `ITEM_COUNT` in 1.x schema :

> ITEM_COUNT: The number of items that have been written out during this execution.

Taking that description, I'd say that the equivalent column in 2.x schema in `WRITE_COUNT` from `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` (same table)